# Leaving plane on transfer of same flight and returning

Tags: technical-stops

I wish to get off plane and walk around airport(to avoid stiffness) when a plane has a stop and passenger continuing on same plane to final destination.

The time is 55 minutes at the stop location.
Can a passenger get off plane and then reboard, using the same seat assignment.
thank you

Comment: This really depends on the airline and the specific flight. In some cases, getting off the plane is mandatory (you may even have to go through a security check and re-board), in other cases it may be permitted, and in many others, it's forbidden. Can you give the airline and the flight number?

Comment: (By forbidden, I also mean sometimes not even physically possible. I've been on flights that have made technical stops for fuel where there's no way off short of opening an emergency exit, and if you did that to stretch your legs, and didn't break your legs on the way out, your resulting incarceration would surely prevent you from making the next leg of your flight.)